# Satellizer JWT token add user Info into payload

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I would like to be able to add the user role into the Payload section of the JWT using Satellizer, so I can access it through $rootScope through my page

this is my Auth controller

```
function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AuthController', AuthController);


function AuthController($auth, $state, $http, $rootScope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.loginErrorText;

    vm.login = function() {

        var credentials = {
            email: vm.email,
            password: vm.password
        }

        // Use Satellizer's $auth service to login
        $auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {

            return $http.get('api/authenticate/user');


        }).catch(function(response) {

                vm.loginErrorText = response.statusText

        }).then(function(response){

            // Stringify the returned data to prepare it
            // to go into local storage
            var user = JSON.stringify(response.data.user);

            // Set the stringified user data into local storage
            localStorage.setItem('user', user);

            // The user's authenticated state gets flipped to
            // true so we can now show parts of the UI that rely
            // on the user being logged in
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;

            // Putting the user's data on $rootScope allows
            // us to access it anywhere across the app
            $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.user;

            // Everything worked out so we can now redirect to
            // the users state to view the data
            console.log(response.data.user.role);
            $state.go('dashboard');                
        });
    }

}

})();
```

and here is run method on that checks for the user role , i can access the id of the user through the sub but is there any way i can pass the user roll to jwt payload section ?

```
 .run(function($rootScope, $state, $auth) {

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

            // Grab the user from local storage and parse it to an object
            var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));  


            if(user) {

                // The user's authenticated state gets flipped to
                // true so we can now show parts of the UI that rely
                // on the user being logged in
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;

                // Putting the user's data on $rootScope allows
                // us to access it anywhere across the app. Here
                // we are grabbing what is in local storage
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;

                //getting user ID from JWT
                console.log('Payload : ' + $auth.getPayload().sub);

                // If the user is logged in and we hit the auth route we don't need
                // to stay there and can send the user to the main state
                if(toState.name === "login") {

                    // Preventing the default behavior allows us to use $state.go
                    // to change states
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // go to the "main" state which in our case is users
                    $state.go('dashboard');
                }       
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The payload is defined in the back-end (Laravel). I assume you are following [this guide](http://ryanchenkie.com/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps/) . In the AuthenticateController, instead of:

```
    //AuthenticateController.php
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
     ...
```

I am using:

```
    //AuthenticateController.php
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');       
        try{
            if (! \Auth::once($credentials)){                
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
                }else{
                    $user = \Auth::user();
                    $customClaims = ['utype' => $user->getUserType()];
                    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user, $customClaims);
                }
    ...
```

So you have to define a `getUserType()` in the model class (User.php), or obtain the `userType` directly from the `$user` object in the `AuthenticateController`. Then use `JWTAuth::fromUser`, as described in the section [creating a token based on a user object](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens#creating-a-token-based-on-a-user-object).